# $y = 2+\frac{ 1}{x^2}$ stretched vertically by a factor or $3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Alright folks, having a little problem with this calculus question. anyone help?

The factor and direction of the given function is to be stretched or compressed are given below. Give an equation for the stretched or compressed graph.

$$y = 2+ \frac{1}{x^2}$$ stretched vertically by a factor or $3$.

Any ideas? Thanks for any input!

Comment: just 3 times the formula

Comment: so when doing a horizontal version what would be the difference? Divide by 3?

Comment: No. You would divide (just) "$x$" by $3$.

Comment: play with [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B2%2B1%2Fx%5E2%2C+2%2B1%2F%283x%29%5E2%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D ]

Answer (score 1):

Just to not leave this question unanswered

To vertically strech the formula by a factor 3, take 3 times the formula so in the example you get:,

$$y = 3 \times \left( 2 + \frac{1}{x^2} \right) = 6+ \frac{3}{x^2}$$

To horizontally strech the formula by a factor 3, replace $ x $ with $ \frac {x}{3} $   you get

$$y =  2 + \frac{1}{\left( \frac{x}{3} \right) ^2} = 2+ \frac{9}{x^2}$$